# Evaluation of vertex function with Feynman Parameters

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, momentum, coordinate-systems, propagator

On page 191 of Peskin & Schroeder, they show that after using Feynman parameters $x, y, z$, the denominator of the integrand of the vertex function is:

$$D = k^2 + 2k(yq - zp) + yq^2 + zp^2 - (x+y)m^2 + i\epsilon,$$

where $p$ is the incoming fermion momentum, $k$ its momentum after it emits a photon, $k’$ after it interacts with the external field with momentum $q = k’-k$.

[image]

My question is how to simplify this expression after setting $\ell := k +yq - zp$ to obtain:

$$D = \ell^2 + xyq^2 - (1-z)^2m^2 + i\epsilon.$$

I got stuck trying:

$$\begin{aligned}D - \ell^2 &= q^2(y-y^2) + p^2(z-z^2) + 2yzqp - (x+y)m^2\\ 
&=q^2y(1-y)+p^2z(1-z)+2yzqp - (1-z)m^2\\
&=q^2y(x+z)+p^2z(y+x) + 2yzqp - (1-z)m^2\\
&=xyq^2 + yz(q^2+p^2 + 2qp) +p^2zx - (1-z)m^2\\
&=xyq^2 + yz(q+p)^2 +p^2zx - (1-z)m^2.\end{aligned}$$

Is it possible to cancel the two middle terms in the last line and obtain a square on the $(1-z)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $q+p = p’$, the momentum of the outgoing fermion, with the same mass as the incoming one $m^2 = p^2$, from my last line:

$$\begin{aligned}D - \ell^2 &= xyq^2 + yzm^2 + m^2zx - (1-z)m^2 \\
&= xyq^2 + z(x+y)m^2 - (1-z)m^2\\
&= xyq^2 + z(1-z)m^2 - (1-z)m^2\\
&= xyq^2 - (1-z)(1-z)m^2. \end{aligned}$$